# Install Thunderbird 52.0 manually and correct

Tags: package-management, thunderbird, lightning

Ubuntu 18.04 - I'm rather new to Ubuntu.

I want to use Thunderbird with 'Lightning'.
I installed Thunderbird via the 'Ubuntu Software' - Thunderbird 60.3.0.
In the *Add-ons Manager* of Thunderbird it states, that Lightning is supported till Thunderbird 52.*
I wanted to install Thunderbird 52.* ***actually*** downloaded version 60.3.0 as `.tar.bz2`.
I opened (not installed) it directly in the folder, where I extracted thunderbird

```
 /home/ferdi/Downloads/thunderbird
```

Here in the *Add-ons Manager* downloading Lightning works well, no issues detected so far.

What I want is Thunderbird with Lightning installed properly as package, so that I can call it in the terminal and see it, when I use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an old Thunderbird version to use Lightning. The extension just got split out and is no longer in the regular add-on store, but instead comes as separate package in the Ubuntu repositories, called `xul-ext-lightning`.

First, remove that old Thunderbird 52 again. Then (if you previously uninstalled it) reinstall the latest Thunderbird version and also install the lightning extension package from the repositories with:

```
sudo apt install thunderbird xul-ext-lightning
```

Comment: Nice, you're welcome. Btw, if that answer fixed your issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left. That way you also mark the question as solved. :)